# Балансировщик нагрузки

Tags: сеть

Ситуация:

Есть 2 провайдера, предоставляющие по езернету (Ethernet) доступ к инету. 2 интерфейса (в настоящем 2 компа с двумя серверами).

Задача:

Сделать балансировщик нагрузки интернет канала, по типу "черной коробки" имеющий 2+ `IN-ethernet` портов для *разных* провайдеров и один выход на свитч/коммутатор раздающий инет в локалку.

Собственно вопросы: есть ли аппаратное исполнение для решения подобной задачи, и соответственно программные решения при отсутствии аппаратных.

Comment: У миротика есть подходящие роутеры (находятся в гугле по фразе "mikrotik router 2 wan"). Но любой балансировщик не тривиальное дело. https://habrahabr.ru/post/190352/ в этой статье например не отрабатывается ситуация с пропуском трафика до одного сайта через разные каналы, т.е. трафик как раз может идти то с одного то с другого. Но часть сайтов чувствительны к смене ip пользователя

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение - использовать **OpenWRT** пакетом **mwan3**.

**OpenWRT** ставится на многие роутеры, можно поставить на обычный компьютер или миниатюрный, например Raspberry Pi.

Можно настроить через конфигурационные файлы https://wiki.openwrt.org/ru/doc/howto/mwan3

Но есть графический интерфейс **luci**, интерфейс для настройки нескольких WAN **uci-app-mwan3**. Разобраться можно методом проб и ошибок за несколько часов.

Можно сделать **fail-over** - использовать основной канал, а при сбоях - резервный. Можно создать ipset с списком IP к которым подключаться через один канал, а к каким через другой.

Можно для разных клиентов в локальной сети использовать разные WAN, или переключиться на один, если второй перестанет работать.

**Но!** Повысить скорость загрузки, например, файла по http, путем объединения каналов (чего часто хотят) невозможно, даже на прямых локальных линках клиент-сервер. Это связано с особенностью протокола TCP - каждый пакет имеет свой порядковый номер. Если их отправлять по двум разным каналам - задержки чуть разные, пакеты будет приходить не по порядку, клиент будет считать, что какие-то пакеты потерялись, повторно запрашивать и, в итоге, это будет работать хуже, чем один канал сам по себе.

Сначала нужно понять какая именно балансировка будет в вашем конкретном случае наиболее эффективна.